# How can I monitor the activities made by a software on a database?

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone have an idea how I can monitor the activities made by a software on a database?

I'll be more specific: let's say I have a software A that writes some data to a SQL Server database; I would like to know in real time once an action is performed by the software, what are the exact tables touched.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Almost all the SQL databases have a log system, but it is really expensive on rss. Your best option is to use a log system instead on the software. IMO.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm actually using Tansact SQL, it is not vailable within the tags

Comment: Which means you are using SQL Server (the tag for Transact-SQL would be `tsql`)

Comment: you can use sql profiler.

Comment: @Nekeniehl 
Thanks for the help I'm going to look that up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what exactly you want to do. Do you just want to see queries being executed against the database in real time? If so, as mentioned by Fabiano Carvalho, SQL Profiler is your best bet. It shows activity on the SQL Server in real time, and allows you to record it.

Be aware that if you fire it up, and simply go with the default settings, depending on how busy your SQL Server is, you might see hundreds or thousands of events fly by. If you are specifically interested in traffic generated by a single application, you should add a filter criteria for that.

SQL Profiler will allow you to inspect the actual query that the application generates (including the values of parameters), which is a great help if you want to debug whether or not the generated queries match the expected ones. Profiler also will show you the server resources used in the execution, and thus is a fantastic tool for performance tuning.

You state that you want to see the exact tables affected, which depending on the application, might not always be directly visible in Profiler, though. If the application, for instance, executes stored procedures, rather than using queries, you might have to dive into the procedure code to determine exactly what happens "under the hood", so to speak.

If you are interested in historic events (Like for auditing purposes), you might want to look into Change Data Capture (CDC), or similar methods.

Comment: Thanks, I seems to be working, I just need to add some filters to get only the transactions happening on one particular databse.